# exception running jax-ws example from doc

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying jax-ws, and while running an example from the javaee 6 tutorial (the oracle javaee tutorial) i run into the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer from class weblogic.wsee.jaxws.tubeline.standard.StandardTubelineDeploymentListener
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.tubeline.standard.StandardTubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(StandardTubelineDeploymentListener.java:117)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerImpl.createServer(WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<init>(WSEndpointImpl.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:199)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:420)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:439)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:91)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:170)
    at ****.****.***.webservices.TimeServerPublisher.main(TimeServerPublisher.java:36)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [IllegalAccessException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html) is thrown when an application tries to reflectively create an instance (other than an array), set or get a field, or invoke a method, but the currently executing method does not have access to the definition of the specified class, field, method or constructor.

It seems that you don't have access to `weblogic.wsee.jaxws.tubeline.standard.StandardTubelineDeploymentListener`.

Check to see if the class is private. That may be the error.